# flutter unwanted refresh multi times

Tags: flutter

parent Widget has refreshindicator
in refresh function there is only check current location

```dart
 Future<void> refresh() async {
    try {
      await Bloc.setLocationCode();
      if (Bloc.permission == false) {
        _locRefreshCheck = false;
        //--------------------->error alert 
        setState(() {});
      }
    } catch (e) {
      _locRefreshCheck = false;
      //--------------------->error alert 
      setState(() {});
    }
    return null;
  }
```

and in child Widget
when i refresh screen (i Don't know why but) child Widget is refreshed twice so  i made `if statement` to skip one refresh out of two

```dart
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    _blocData = WeatherBlocProvider.of(context).bloc;
    if (streamCall) {
      _blocData.forceRefreshAll(context);
      streamCall = !streamCall;
    } else {
      streamCall = !streamCall;
    }
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

the problem is when i touch the screen and slide screen down very lightly(before refreshindicator works, so not even can't see `circularprograss Widget`) the refresh works. so Widgets are rebuilt several time. when i want error test alertDialog come out several times. how can i solve this?

----for more info
i use streambuilder in childWidget using http request